# The argument type 'Iterable<Text>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget' in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got an error on this line of my code and do not find any solution for that.

`child: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {`

The argument type 'Iterable' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

This is my code:

```
      Widget buildCategtoryFirestore() => StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData) {
            return null;
          } else {
            List<DropdownMenuItem> categoryItems= [];
            
            for(int i=0;i<snapshot.data.docs.length;i++) {
              //DocumentSnapshot snap=snapshot.data.docs[i];
              categoryItems.add(
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return Text(document['title']);
                  }), 
                  value: "$document['title']",
                ),
              );
              return DropdownButtonFormField(
                items: categoryItems,
              );
            }
          }
        },
      );
```

Can anybody help why I got this error and how to fix it?

Comment: from my understanding, you're not passing a widget so make sure to change it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in another community. I works with this code:

```
Widget buildCategtoryFirestore() => StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('petertesthausen@gmail.com_categories').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

      List<DropdownMenuItem> _categoryItems;

      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("no data...");
      } else {
        _categoryItems = snapshot.data.docs.map((doc) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(EncryptionDecryption.decryptAES(doc['title'])),
            value: EncryptionDecryption.decryptAES(doc['title']),
          );
        }).toList();
        return DropdownButtonFormField(
          hint: Text('Kategorie'),
          items: _categoryItems,
          onChanged: (value) => {print(value)},
        );
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns an Iterable, not a single Widget which is expected by DropdownMenuItem.

```
snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return Text(document['title']);
                  })
```

Maybe you can try to take the first one if you don't expect a list, e.g.:

```
snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        return Text(document['title']);
                      }).first
```

But be carefull if your list is empty, it will throw an error.

Comment: I work for my previous error. But I now have an error in the line of the 'value: "$document['title']",' where it says 'document' is not defined.

Comment: From what I read on FireStore documentation, you should replace `snapshot.data.docs` by `snapshot.data.documents`. Can you try it and see if it helps? Also, you can use the debugger to better see what there is in the snapshot.data variable

Comment: I first tried with 'documents' but then I got this error -> The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'. Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'

Comment: My bad, try to replace DocumentSnapshot type with QueryDocumentSnapshot and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` returns an iterable. You will have to add `.toList()` for the error to go away.
Like this:

```
snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return Text(document['title']);
              }).toList();
```

However, you probably wanted to do something like this:
This is much more effective as it will loop through the items only once.

```
              List<DropdownMenuItem> categoryItems = [];

              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                DocumentSnapshot snap=snapshot.data.docs[i];
                categoryItems.add(
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text('${snap.data()['title']}'),
                    value: snap.data()['title'],
                  ),
                );
                return DropdownButtonFormField(
                  items: categoryItems,
                );
              }
```

Comment: When I try your first suggestion I got this error on the same line as before:

The argument type 'List<Text>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

When I try the second solution I can start the app but my snapshot  returns null.so it returns the first if statement which is also null.